# How to invalidate varnish cached object with Ban expression

Tags: regex, varnish, cache-control, varnish-vcl

Consider my requested url is [www.example.com/foo/emplooyee?names](http://www.example.com/foo/emplooyee?names) = test1;test2.
and varnish stores this entire URL along with query parameters to uniquely identify the cache.

now, in my backend, I'm running one service and which I'm supposed to configure as whenever there are changes in **names** (i.e. test1 or test2) is should fire an HTTP ban with an older name (single name at a time in ban expression) to invalidate all the cached URL which entered with similar names.

Questions:
My client request url could be like this,

- [www.example.com/foo/emplooyee?names](http://www.example.com/foo/emplooyee?names) = test1;test2
- [www.example.com/foo/emplooyee?names](http://www.example.com/foo/emplooyee?names) = test1;
- [www.example.com/foo/emplooyee?names](http://www.example.com/foo/emplooyee?names) = test2;test1;test3;test4
- [www.example.com/foo/emplooyee?names](http://www.example.com/foo/emplooyee?names) = test1;test4.

How to write a VCL code and in Ban expression to invalidate all object which has query parameter as **test1**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the VCL code you need for banning:

```
vcl 4.1;

acl purge {
    "localhost";
    "192.168.55.0"/24;
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
            return(synth(405));
        }
        if(!req.http.x-invalidate-pattern) {
            return(purge);
        }
        ban("obj.http.x-url ~ " + req.http.x-invalidate-pattern
            + " && obj.http.x-host == " + req.http.host);
        return (synth(200,"Ban added"));
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.http.x-url = bereq.url;
    set beresp.http.x-host = bereq.http.host;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    unset resp.http.x-url;
    unset resp.http.x-host;
}
```

Here's an example HTTP request to invalidate all requests that contain a `test1` value in the query string:

```
PURGE / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
X-Invalidate-Pattern: ^/foo/emplooyee\?names=([^;]+;)*test1(;[^;]+)*$
```

Here's the same request via `curl`:

```
curl -XPURGE -H'X-Invalidate-Pattern: ^/foo/emplooyee\?names=([^;]+;)*test1(;[^;]+)*$' http://www.example.com
```

This VCL snippet has the flexibility to remove multiple items from cache through banning, but if you don't set the pattern through the `X-Invalidate-Pattern` header, it will just remove the URL itself from cache.

Here's an example where we just remove `http://www.example.com/foo/emplooyee?names=test1` from the cache:

```
curl -XPURGE 'http://www.example.com/foo/emplooyee?names=test1'
```

> Don't forget to modify the `acl` block in the VCL code and add the right IP addresses or IP ranges.

Comment: Thanks, @Thijs Feryn, it's worked exactly the way I needed.

Comment: What happnes when try to ban something which is not present in Cached object at? will it be just a new entry in ban.list?

Comment: Indeed, it will be added to the ban list and will disappear after a while when no objects match it. Any object that is added after the ban was added, will not match the ban. Long story short: don't worry, you're safe.